# How to install required packages for feeds spreadsheet module as shown required by Composer Manager?

Tags: 7, feeds, composer

[image]

**Modules being used**
[Composer Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager)
[Feeds Spreadsheet](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_spreadsheet)

**Requirement**

 
I need to install the package as mentioned in the configuration page of module composer manager.
The error shown is as given below.

```
Composer's install command must be run to generate the autoloader and install the required packages.
Refer to the instructions on the Composer Manager project page for installing packages.
```

I have access to Cpanel but don't have command line access right now, how can I install the required packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have 2 options:

1. Ask your hosting provider to let you install and run Composer, and access it via the command line
2. Run the Composer install locally, then push all the files up (including the vendor folder)

Comment: I am not sure if its a silly question, can you mention exactly which files should be pushed to the live? is the vendor folder under root directory  and are there any other files which I need to move?

Comment: You'll have to inspect your own environment to know for sure, the vendor path is configurable. IIRC I've seen it in /sites/default/files/vendor or similar when previously using Composer Manager. As far as composer is concerned that's all you should need to push up (though pushing composer.json and composer.lock into version control would be wise)

Comment: so from your comments I see only thing which needs to be moved is the vendor directory (probably under sites/default/files/vendor) and no  need to move composer.json and composer.lock ? is that right?

Comment: I wound up ripping this module out on a D7 project and just using Composer and a deployment method. Do note that this requires editing index.php to require the autoloader.

Comment: One hurdle was fixed , when 
1) I downloaded all the root directory locally 
2) ran the command composer init
3) Ran the command composer install
4) copied vendor folder from the root which was generated and placed it inside sites/all/vendor
This helped me show that package was installed, now will check if that helps,Thanks @Kevin